# Is it possible to create a symbolic multivariate normal distribution with sympy?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, sympy, symbolic-math

It is possible to create a multivariate normal with given values for mean and variance:

```
from sympy.stats import Normal
from sympy import *

mu = Matrix([1,0])
Sigma = Matrix([[1,0],[0,1]])
X = Normal("X", mu, Sigma)
```

I would like to do the same with symbolic matrices:

```
n=5
mu = MatrixSymbol("mu", n, 1)
Sigma = MatrixSymbol("Sigma", n, n)
X = Normal("X", mu, Sigma)
```

which leads to a `TypeError: Mix of Matrix and Scalar symbols`

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using sympy 1.4 I think you need to use:

```
from sympy.stats.joint_rv_types import MultivariateNormalDistribution
```

but your above code just works in the development version, i.e. the upcoming version 1.5.

Comment: hm, the sample code works, but the distribution X is basically unusable. Even simple things like variance(X) throw an exception.

Comment: sorry, I don't know about this, have only used other parts of the library and thought the pointer would be useful!  maybe you could post another question describing more of what you're trying to accomplish?